# Sort and find in Mongo but fetch only specific fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I wonder if I can sort and find in Mongo but return only specific fields.

This command sorts the results by the field properties.aar but returns all the fields from the dataset.

```
db.samplecol.find().sort({"properties.aar":1})
```

Result (an example):

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ad70f71f2119236741ffb03"), "geometry" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 119.6164, 4.7121 ] }, "type" : "Feature", "properties" : { "STATUS" : "0", "TIMESTAMP" : "2013-12-31 18:49:00.000", "aar" : "205580000", "COURSE" : "175", "SPEED" : "153", "HEADING" : "176" } }
```

I wonder if I can return only the geometry.coordinates.

**Update**

The results aren't sorted based on the field properties.aar. The code that works for me is (pymongo):

```
db.samplecol.find({}, {"properties.aar":1,"geometry.coordinates":1, "_id":0}).sort([("properties.aar", pymongo.ASCENDING)])
```

So, @Neil Lunn please don't judge so fast to mark a question.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called 'projection' :

Check out the documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-the-specified-fields-and-the-id-field-only).

> A projection can explicitly include several fields by setting the  to 1 in the projection document. The following operation returns all documents that match the query. In the result set, only the item, status and, by default, the _id fields return in the matching documents.
>
> db.inventory.find( { status: "A" }, { item: 1, status: 1 } )

If you are using mongoose, you can use the `.select()` method, more info [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select).

Comment: The results would be sorted based on properties.aar?

Comment: Can you hel me with the query?

Comment: ``db.collection.find(
  {_id:'someId'},   
  {'someField':1})
  .sort('someOtherField':1)``